# compare and cropping theimage in python using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have two images below :

Image1:

[image]

Image2:

[image]

I want to crop `Image2` in the same manner as `Image1`. So if I read all the document of my folder then script should automatically crop the image in the same manner as in `Image1`.
I am using the below code for cropping.

```
image = cv2.imread(path+'passport3.jpg')
y=280
x=0
h=373
w=546
crop = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow('Image', crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However If I crop another image then this script does not work there.For example if I run the above script for below image then I am getting unexpected output :

[image]

Comment: Beware that the passport no. is still visible on the side of the last images. While it is allowed to post personal information on Stack Overflow, I strongly advise against it.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error: your 'unexpected output' is a different image than image2?

Comment: @funie200- edited the images as requested.However this images are masked images taken from internet.

Comment: @Adityasharma Okay, in that case ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

Resize the image to standard size before cropping because you are cropping with respect to constant position, height and width.

```
image=cv2.resize(image,(500,500))
```

I tried it with both of the given examples and its worked.